# Writing the chosen plugin in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox, jquery-chosen

Actually I'm trying to write a pure JavaScript plugin for combo-box (dropdown + input text) ,I was trying to write the  [chosen plugin](http://github.com/harvesthq/chosen) without using jquery, but I am stuck at the following part:

```
  (function() {
     var $, Chosen, root, _ref,
     __hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty,
     __extends = function(child, parent) { for (var key in parent) { if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; } function ctor() { this.constructor = child; } ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; child.prototype = new ctor(); child.__super__ = parent.prototype; return child; };

     root = this;

     $ = jQuery;

    $.fn.extend({
     chosen: function(options) {
     if (!AbstractChosen.browser_is_supported()) {
     return this;
    }
    return this.each(function(input_field) {
    var $this;

    $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.hasClass("chzn-done")) {
      return $this.data('chosen', new Chosen(this, options));
    }
   });
  }
});
```

What would be the corresponding javascript code for this piece of jquery code. If anyone have this kind of plugin or example then please give the link.
Thanks in advance